# Name of this theorem? (Generalization of the class equation)

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

> Let $X$ be a nonempty finitr set and $G$ be a finite group acting on $X$.
>
> Let $G.x_1,...,G.x_n$ be the distinct orbits of $G$.
>
> Define $F(X)=\{x\in X : \forall g\in G, g.x=x\}$.
>
> Then $|X|=|F(X)|+\sum_{x_i\notin F(X)} |G:G_{x_i}|$.

I remember that this theorem has some specific name, but I cannot remember.. What's the name of this theorem?

Comment: I think you may be thinking of Burnside's lemma about the number of orbits, but what you wrote just uses the fact that $$x\in X\implies |\mathcal Orb(x)|=[G : G_x]$$ and, of course, the fact that $\;x\in F(X)\iff |\mathcal Orb(x)|=1\;$ .

Comment: What is sometimes called the modified class equation is a special case of this result ( in that case, $|Z(G)|$ corresponds to $|F(G)|$, and the orbits (under conjugation) of size $1$ have been separated out).